# Insert data into MySQL database from Javascript calling PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have the below code which calls a .php file to insert data into a MySQL database, but cant seem to get the .php file to run. Any suggestions?

I am very new to script so i am trying this registration form example. The database, 'college', with its table, 'registration', seems to be fine, but no php code executes. It must be something really simple but i cant seem to work it out?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#register").click(function() {
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var cpassword = $("#cpassword").val();
if (name == '' || email == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
} else if ((password.length) < 8) {
alert("Password should atleast 8 character in length...!!!!!!");
} else if (!(password).match(cpassword)) {
alert("Your passwords don't match. Try again?");
} else {
 //alert(name); //This line reads fine
 $.post("register.php",
 {
 name1: name,
 email1: email,
 password1: password
}, 
function(data) {
 if (data == 'You have Successfully Registered.....') {
 $("form")[0].reset();
}
alert(data);
});
}
});
});
```

```css
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Winchester12"); // Establishing connection with server..
$db = mysql_select_db("college", $connection); // Selecting Database.
$name=$_POST['name1']; // Fetching Values from URL.
$email=$_POST['email1'];
echo $email;
$password= sha1($_POST['password1']); // Password Encryption, If you like you can also leave sha1.
// Check if e-mail address syntax is valid or not
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Sanitizing email(Remove unexpected symbol like <,>,?,#,!, etc.)
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo "Invalid Email.......";
}else{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email='$email'");
$data = mysql_num_rows($result);
if(($data)==0){
$query = mysql_query("insert into registration(name, email, password) values ('$name', '$email', '$password')"); // Insert query
if($query){
echo "You have Successfully Registered.....";
}else
{
echo "Error....!!";
}
}else{
echo "This email is already registered, Please try another email...";
}
}
mysql_close ($connection);
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Squash Registration Form</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<!-- Include CSS File Here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<!-- Include JS File Here -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="registration.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
<form class="form" method="post" action="#">
<h2>Squash Registration Form</h2>
<label>Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="dname" id="name">
<label>Email :</label>
<input type="text" name="demail" id="email">
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<label>Confirm Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword">
<input type="button" name="register" id="register" value="Register">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementing value in PHP script not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573476/incrementing-value-in-php-script-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a path related issue.

you might want to review the path to the **register.php** file to be sure its in the right place.

Comment: I checked and all the files are in the same directory

Comment: i need a php compiler perhaps? :)

Comment: Install xamp on ur pc then

Answer (score 0):

It seems that nothing is passed to register.php file. Please try with 'ajax' instead of jquery post.